# RTL/LTR layout drawable as Background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout

I have to create a card view like this:

[image: CardLayout]

I create the layout in Xml like this:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardDevice"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorSurface"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/gradiant_device"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iconArea"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iconArea"/>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/iconArea"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/backgroundColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardIcon"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:cardCornerRadius="14dp"
                app:cardElevation="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgIcon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:padding="12dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_lamp_off"/>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Device Name and Status -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/iconArea"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iconArea"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/iconArea">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_lamp_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Lamp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_device_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
                android:text="On"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My problem is to create that **gradiant_device** drawable for glowing that way Start from under the card and ends to the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:centerX="0%"
    android:centerY="50%"
    android:endColor="?attr/colorSurface"
    android:gradientRadius="200%p"
    android:startColor="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:type="radial"/>
</shape>
```

I need that gradiant start from under the card in RTL layouts also (when icon card is at right > gradiant **start at right** *not left*!) *ALL OTHER VIEWS GETS RTL & LTR BUT gradiantBackground NOT*

I also try to create a RTL and LTR files for **gradiant_device** separated! But its only on in xml design preview and not work in Run: if help I SET the language with this code on app start:

```
private fun setLocale(localeToSet: String) {
    val localeListToSet = LocaleList(Locale(localeToSet))
    LocaleList.setDefault(localeListToSet)
    resources.configuration.setLocales(localeListToSet)
    createConfigurationContext(resources.configuration)
}
```

Comment: You have to recreate the activity for the locale changes to take effect

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi ok but i set the language also when app opens to RTL language before create and all layouts do the RTL they should but this gradiantBackground !